# Inline editing in visual force inconsistent

Tags: actionsupport, inline-visualforce

I have a vf page where i have few columns and i have used inline editing for the columns, the code is as follows:

```
    <apex:commandButton value="Add Session" action="{!createNewSession}" id="btnAddSession"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="btnSave" style="display:none"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="btnCancel" style="display:none" reRender="PanelId"/>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstSessions}" var="Session" rendered="{!lstSessions.size>0}" id="pbt">
    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Session__c.Fields.Session_Status__c.Label}">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Session.Session_Status__c}"/> 
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Session__c.Fields.GL_Department__c.Label}">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Session.GL_Department__c}"/> 
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Session__c.Fields.Quantity__c.Label}">
        <apex:actionRegion >
            <table border="0" id="table_quantity">
                <tr>
                    <td border="0">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Session.Quantity__c}">
                            <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="btnSave,btnCancel" hideOnEdit="btnAddSession" rendered="{!Session.Session_Status__c != 'Booked'}"/>
                        </apex:outputField>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Session__c.Fields.Unit_Cost__c.Label}">
        <apex:actionRegion >
            <table border="0" id="table_unit_cost">
                <tr>
                    <td border="0">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!Session.Unit_Cost__c}">
                            <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="btnSave,btnCancel" hideOnEdit="btnAddSession" rendered="{!Session.Session_Status__c != 'Booked'}"/>
                        </apex:outputField>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:column>                
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

The inline editing is not consistent it is working for the first column, but it is not working for the first record in the second column, but it is working for all the remaining records in the second column.

Please reply,
Thanks in advance.

Regards, 
Sushma.

Comment: What have you tried? What's your browser and have you eliminated browser compatibility as a potential cause? Have you tried changing the order of your columns, or removing columns until the code works?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I have tried this out in ie,mozilla, chrome. I have also tried by inter changing the column- the first column allows the update while the rest do not allow, this is only for the first row of the pageblocktable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does seem odd. I've reproduced your sample in my own DE org and cannot reproduce the issue. For reference my code is [here](https://gist.github.com/4705584) if you need to compare. My only suggestion is to compare the two rows, maybe clone the first row and see if the issue occurs on the new row as well. Doing tests like this will help you confirm if its data related which I suspect is. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrew,
Yes this is very strange.
I copied the code which you tried out in my developer org, even this code is showing the same issues- (not allowing the value to be updated)

Comment: Yes very strange, I had no such issue, as is shown in my screenshot. Though of course I was not using your object, I created one similar, maybe you could try that, if it works compare the objects? Also did you try my recommendation above to clone the records effected to see if the issue also occured on these new cloned records? This would help to understand if this is data related or not?

Comment: Actually I am not having this issue for this object only, am facing this issue on all the VF pages (in the org)in which I have inline edit similar functionality. So not able to identify the cause of this issue. These pages work in few org's while they don't work in few org's. In fact i tired the same code posted by you in another org where it worked, but still inconsistent in this org.

Comment: In that case, if the code and object and data is identical in both orgs, I would raise a case giving Salesforce support access to both orgs and ask them to explain. It must be some config difference perhaps (have you check UI setting in Setup, Object Security, Profiles etc?). If you have, a case is the way to go. I hope my answer has been useful to you in the meantime! :)

Comment: I have raised a case with sales force, will let you know when this issue is solved. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: The case was solved by salesforce support.

Comment: Thats great news, would you be able to provide more information here for future readers?

Comment: I too don't have details of how it was solved, I was only informed by Sales force support that it was fixed over many instances. I verify it in my orgs and found out that it was fixed.